# JSON Authorization failed. My error is 'Bad MAC'

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I want to access the JSON page of a product in the JD Sport application. For that I used the `Charles` application which allowed me to obtain the following url and all the headers necessary to access this page:

https://prod.jdgroupmesh.cloud/stores/jdsportsfr/products/15958093_jdsportsfr

When I want to access the JSON page via my next python script, the page returns this error :

```
{'error': {'message': 'API key is not valid. Request authorization failed. Bad MAC'}}
```

I don't understand what I need to do to get the information on the JSON page.

Thank you in advance

```
import requests
import json


headers = {
    'Host': 'prod.jdgroupmesh.cloud',
    'X-NewRelic-ID': 'VQYDUFVWDRABVFVRBwMOV10=',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'X-API-Key': 'B3B51B56ADC34016A6FEF7F8C337B836',
    'mesh-version': 'cart=4',
    'MESH-Commerce-Channel': 'iphone-app',
    'User-Agent': 'jdsportsfr/6.8.5.2214 (iphone-app; iOS 14.4)',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr-fr', 
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'X-Request-Auth': 'Hawk id="f2188a5b06", mac="V/227yl11UzqV0Wr3Mb0A8SeOVeN94vY1QEXLEucBXc=", ts="1613150841", nonce="8ZZJMN"',
    'mesh-version': 'cart=4'
}


params = (
    ('expand', 'variations,informationBlocks,customisations'),
    ('channel', 'iphone-app'),
)

stock_json_raw = requests.get('https://prod.jdgroupmesh.cloud/stores/jdsportsfr/products/15958093_jdsportsfr/imageSpinSet',headers=headers, params=params).text.strip()#, headers=headers, params=params).text.strip()
stock_json = json.loads(stock_json_raw)
print(stock_json)
```

Comment: looks like there is something wring with: `mac="V/227yl11UzqV0Wr3Mb0A8SeOVeN94vY1QEXLEucBXc="`

Comment: Yes I think, but I don't know what i can do

Comment: where did you get those headers?

Comment: server may generate uniqe value for every request. If you get this value from some request then they may be outdated and maybe you may have to run other request to get correct value before you send this request. All may depends what you find in API documentation.

Comment: BTW: `ts=` can means `TimeStamp` and it may be used to define when this value was created - and then server may use this value to refuse connection when it is too old. But I'm only guessing and you should check API documentation.

Comment: you could add URL for page which sends this request - and then we can check it in web browser or using `Charles` (or other proxy server - ie. `mintproxy`) to see how it works.

Comment: Hello, the url id : https://prod.jdgroupmesh.cloud/stores/jdsportsfr/products/15958093_jdsportsfr

I know now that I have to generate mac, nonce and ts with my python code. But I don't how to do.

Answer (score 0):

you gotta use mohawk, a way to authenticate with there servers. Youll need to get the mesh keys for it. Then you will be able to generate the entire x-request-auth header with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, do you know how i can obtain the mesh keys ?